# iframe updating only once

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube

By clicking the thumbnail image, original video(youtube iframe) is loaded to main video DIV.
it works but, when i click to another thumbnail white one video is playing, the iframe is not updating.

```
<div>
        <div class="mainvideo" id="nowplaying"></div>
                <div class="youtube" id="0Z4rczATGdw"></div>
                <div class="youtube" id="MaQmyhkGNm0"></div>
                <div class="youtube" id="L-IrZdyqS-o"></div>
                <div class="youtube" id="e9wfybrwFag"></div>
                <div class="youtube" id="MaQmyhkGNm0"></div>
                <script src="youtube.js"></script>
</div>

http://jsfiddle.net/WLzua/
```

when clicked on another thumbnail while iframe loaded on nowplaying(div):
chrome console: Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 youtube.js:7
y.onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<iframe src="" id="player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="701" height="308" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".youtube").click(function(){
               var Link = $(this).attr("id");
               $("#player").attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+Link);
            });
        });  
</script>
```